# \ref shows the right label but jumps to the wrong \label

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats, appendices

in this MWE you can see/explore (hopefully, as it does not work for me) that `\ref{tab:2}` produces the right label but if you click on it, it will lead you to the `\label{tab:1}`.
`\usepackage{appendix}` and `\begin{appendix} ... \end{appendix}` doesn't helped and as I assume I'm using the `\label` at the right position.

EDIT: The solution putting the \numbering behind the hyperref worked well(!), but another error occured in combination with subfigures. The label does not fit anymore, if the \numbering is placed before the include of the subfigure package. I´ve heard that hyperref should be the last included package for some reasons, but as solution for this error: Can I just place the \usepackage{subfigure} after hyperref and \numbering?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  allcolors = blue,
]{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}
    \section{sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab one}
        \label{tab:1}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    MWE, more in the appendix, tab \ref{tab:2}
    \section{sec two}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \subfigure[left fig \label{fig:left}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{default.png}}
        \subfigure[right fig \label{fig:right}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{default.png}}
    \caption{left and right fig}
    \end{figure}
    Next Problem: subfigures \ref{fig:left}
    \appendix
    \clearpage
    \section{appendix}
    \subsection{to sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab two}
        \label{tab:2}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for a long time. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Since the `subfig` package is known for several issues regarding `hyperref`, I would use the `subcaption` package. (I'm sorry for the shameless self-advertising here but the broken `hyperref` support of `subfig` was the main reason why I decided to write the `subcaption` package.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`hyperref` supports `\numberwithin`, but only if it awares of it. Therefore, `\numberwithin` should be used *after* package `hyperref`.

**Further remarks:**

- Option `allcolors` simplifies the setting of the colors to one color with option `colorlinks`.
- Package `hyperref` detects driver `pdftex` automatically, it does not need to be set explicitly.
- KOMAScript option `captions=tableheading` fixes the skip settings around table captions, which are used above the table. Thus, the empty line hack can be removed.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  allcolors = blue,
]{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}
    \section{sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab one}
        \label{tab:1}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    MWE, more in the appendix, tab \ref{tab:2}

    \appendix
    \clearpage
    \section{appendix}
    \subsection{to sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab two}
        \label{tab:2}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked well! but now another issue appeared using the packages grapicx and subfigures, I´ve edited my MWE

Answer (score 6):

pdftex is warning you in the log that the destination anchors are not unique

```
l.43         \caption{Tab two}
                              pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same 
identifier (name{table.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
```

As Heiko wrote in this case the easiest is to move the `\numberwithin` commands and let hyperref take care of it. A manual solution is to redefine `\theHtable` so that gives an unique representation.

Also avoid to insert spaces with `\ \\` after a caption. Such spaces can be changed by options and setting lengths.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,
               captions=tableabove,  %better spacing after table captions
               ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}


\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  citecolor = {blue},
  linkcolor = {blue},
  urlcolor  = {blue}]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\theHtable{\thesection.\thetable} 

\begin{document}
    \section{sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab one}
        \label{tab:1}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    MWE, more in the appendix, tab \ref{tab:2}

    \appendix
    \clearpage
    \section{appendix}
    \subsection{to sec one}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Tab two}
        \label{tab:2}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```